# Значение input - чтение, присвоение (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, input

Как посчитать числа в двух **input** ?

Укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибки в коде.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="first"> + <input type="text" id="second"> = <input type="text" id="result">
<button id="evaluate">Evaluate</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
var second = document.getElementById("second").value;
var ev = document.getElementById("evaluate");
evaluate.onclick= function() {
    var res = first + second;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=res;
}
```

Comment: `.value` в обоих случаях будут рассматриваться кодом не как тип `integer`, как надо для последующих математических функций, а как `string` - текст. Вам надо их оба перевести... Грубый вариант - `first *=1`. Т.е. умножая js меняет тип переменной. Тогда и сложение сработает...

Comment: Мне кажеться или онклик срабатывает не на том блоке? Вы указали путь к блоку в `ev` а онклик вызываете у `evaluate`.

Answer (score 1):

Как совершенно верно сказал [cyadvert](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186791/cyadvert), ваш скрипт забирает из полей их значения — строки. Вам нужно перевести их в числа, например, так:

```
evaluate.onclick= function() {
  var res = Number(first) + Number(second);
  document.getElementById("result").value = res;
}
```